# what is "default" in a config file (redis-server in this case)

Tags: redis, configuration-files

This may sound to be a very silly or basic doubt, but here's my question.
 In this redis server config file
https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/2.8/redis.conf#L14

Consider the config, log-level notice.

What if I don't use this line :

log-level notice

in my config file. What will be it's default value? 
Or does all the configs set in this example config file are default by themselves inside redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Redis log level with `config get loglevel`. After you comment log level property and restart Redis service. You will see that default log level is `notice`.